# How to import Newline Delimited JSON into Navicat or Bigquery

Tags: database, google-bigquery, navicat, ndjson

I am trying to import a ndjson file into either Navicat or Bigquery.

Neither seem to have a option to allow for "array of strings"

Is there any way to achieve this? or is there another tool that will allow this.`JSON   Value
UUID    string
databaseID  integer
title   string
alternativeTitle    array of strings
contributor array of objects
contributor.contributorName string
contributor.contributorType string
contributorRole array of strings
contributor.contributorURI  string
date    array of strings
dateStart   string
dateEnd string
language    array of strings
description string
note    array of objects
note.type   string
note.text   string
subjectTopical  array of objects
subjectTopical.text string
subjectTopical.URI  string
subjectName array of objects
subjectName.text    string
subjectName.URI string
subjectGeographic   array of objects
subjectGeographic.text  string
subjectGeographic.URI   string
subjectTemporal array of objects
subjectTemporal.text    string
subjectTemporal.URI string
subjectTitle    array of objects
subjectTitle.text   string
subjectTitle.URI    string
resourceType    array of strings
genre   array of objects
genre.text  string
genre.URI   string
identifierBNumber   string
identifierAccessionNumber   string
identifierCallNumber    string
identifierISBN  string
identifierISSN  string
identifierInterviewID   string
identifierPostcardID    string
identifierLCCN  string
identifierOCLCRLIN  string
physicalDescriptionExtent   array of strings
physicalDescriptionForm array of strings
publisher   array of strings
placeOfPublication  array of strings
collectionUUID  string
containerUUID   string
collectionTitle string
containerTitle  string
parentHierarchy string
numberOfCaptures    integer
-   string
captures    array of strings
digtalCollectionsURL    string`

Comment: Can you please add json schema of your data to the question?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports nested/repeated fields, so you can have field of type STRING with REPEATED mode

See more in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery and especially check `configuration.load.schema.fields[].mode` in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load

Comment: I am not from Google Team, so unfortunately, having just that screenshot is not helpful for me to provide further answering. Hope, Google Team members will be able to help you by knowing jobid. Unless, you post more specific question with details enough to answer it by non Googlers :o)